# Question about slice category from Allufi chapter 0

Tags: category-theory

I have a quick question maybe there is something trivial confusing me. So, here I don't know why we have $f_1$ and $f_2$ the way they are. Shouldn't $f_1 : Z_2 \rightarrow A$ and $f_2 : Z_1 \rightarrow A$. Because, then we will have that $\sigma : f_1 \rightarrow f_2$ defined as $\sigma \ f_1 = f_1 \sigma = f_2$ 
[image]

Comment: You can notate it however you want, though your notation is much less intuitive, but why do you think $f_1\sigma=\sigma f_1$? There's no reason that would be true.

Comment: I understand now @KevinCarlson. So, the thing that was confusing me is that I was getting intuition coming from set theory. I mean Hom_C(A,B) isn't really a "function" connecting A and B. It is actually a set that satisfies the properties of functions but it doesn't really need to behave like one. I completely understand this example now.